# disable button in specific time using js

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to disable the button base on time. If the time exceeds 5pm then the button will disable. I got my code but I don't know if it is the proper. Please help me to solve this . sorry I'm not that good in javascript.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    <script>
        function startTime() {
            var today = new Date();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();
            m = checkTime(m);
            s = checkTime(s);
            document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
                h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
        }
        function checkTime(i) {
            if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i };  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
            return i;
        }

        function buttonTime() {
            if (checkTime() > 17) {
                document.getElementById('button').disabled = true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

    <div id="txt"></div>
    <form action="login.php">
        <button class="btn btn-info" id="button" type="submit"> Submit </button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have edited your question and use `ctrl+k` to format the code

Comment: Hi sir @dave can you help me with my problem?

Comment: I am not good at this stuff but community will surely help you, just wait :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy. You needn't compute minutes and seconds as you did in your fiddle.

All you need is to fetch what is the current hour and place a condition on the same.

For example -

```
var time = new Date();
var hours = time.getHours();
if(hours>17) {
//your button disabling logic will come here
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Then I have to reply my script code with yours sir @Aseem?

Comment: try out this logic. no need to reply with the code.